# Как отправлять файлы в telegram?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Всем привет не могу разобраться как вставить документ и фотографии для отправки телеграмм бот, прочитал столько доков запутался не понимаю как связать фотографии и документы у них разные переменные, есть ли один не понял помогите пожалуйста )
Текстовые поля отправляются у меня, а вот как отправлять файлы не разобрался (

```
 <?php
    $token = "2029049267:AVVVVugguguybyuffsadigfh6GGGGGGGh14sXjrHHHhb-lIIIIIUUUAQ";
    $chat_id = "69858555";
    $values = $hook->getValues();
    
    // Получаем название формы
    $formName = $modx->getOption('formName', $formit->config, 'form-'.$modx->resource->get('id'));
    
    // Получаем ip адрес отправителя
    $ip = $modx->getOption('REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER, '');
    
    
    // Берем данные с формы
    $name= $values[name];
    $phone= $values['phone'];
    $email= $values['email'];
    $length= $values['length'];
    $width= $values['width'];
    $height= $values['height'];
    
    $circulation= $values['circulation'];
    
    
    $arr = array(
    "IP" => $ip,
    "Длина" => $length,
    "Ширина" => $width,
    "Высота" => $height,
    "Количество" => $circulation,
    "Имя" => $name,
    "Телефон" => $phone,
    "Email" => $email);
    
    if($length){
        $arr["Длина"] = $length;
    }
    if($width){
        $arr["Ширина"] = $width;
    }
    if($height){
        $arr["Высота"] = $height;
    }
    if($circulation){
        $arr["Количество"] = $circulation;
    }
    if($email){
        $arr["Email"] = $email;
    }
    if($phone){
        $arr["Телефон"] = $phone;
    }
    
    if($email){
        $arr["Email"] = $email;
    }
    
    
    
    
    $txt = '<b>Заполнена форма - '.$formName."</b>\n";
    // Цикл по массиву (собираем сообщение)
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) { 
         $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b>: ".$value." \n"; 
      }
    
    // Отправляем сообщение посредством cURL
    $website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;
    $params=[
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => $txt,
    'parse_mode' => 'html'
    ];
    $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $modx->log(MODX_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, $result);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    //Возвращаем true – это особенность написания хуков для FormIt.
    return true;
```

Сама форма обратной связи

```
<form  action="[[~[*id]]]]" method="post" class="ajax_form af_example form-horizontal">
   <div class="group">      
      <input id="length" name="length" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label for="length">Длина:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="group">      
      <input id="width" name="width" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label for="width">Ширина:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="group">      
      <input id="height" name="height" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label for="height">Высота:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="group">      
      <input id="circulation" name="circulation" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label for="circulation">Тираж:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="upload-file__wrapper">
      <input type="file" name="files" id="upload-file__input_1" class="upload-file__input" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .doc, .docx, .txt">
      <label class="upload-file__label" for="upload-file__input_1">
         <svg class="upload-file__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path d="M286 384h-80c-14.2 1-23-10.7-24-24V192h-87.7c-17.8 0-26.7-21.5-14.1-34.1L242.3 5.7c7.5-7.5 19.8-7.5 27.3 0l152.2 152.2c11.6 11.6 3.7 33.1-13.1 34.1H320v168c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24zm216-8v112c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-23-23V366c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h136v8c0 31 24.3 56 56 56h80c30.9 0 55-26.1 57-55v-8h135c13.3 0 24 10.6 24 24zm-124 88c0-11-9-20-19-20s-19 9-20 20 9 19 20 20 21-9 20-20zm64 0c0-12-9-20-20-20s-20 9-19 20 9 20 20 20 21-9 20-20z">
            </path>
         </svg>
         <span class="upload-file__text">Прикрепить файл</span>
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="group">      
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label for="name">Имя:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="group">      
      <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label for="phone">Телефон:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="group">      
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-success d-block mx-auto" type="submit" name="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед заново? На гитхабе полно реализаций телеграм-ботов под разные движки. Возьмите оттуда.

Comment: это modx revo использую дополнение ajaxForm, если вы знаете как реализовать через modx revo выслушаю вас?

Comment: Ну раз Вам самому лень... Первый же запрос в гугл по тегам `modx` `revolution` `teleram` `github` выдал ссылку `https://github.com/mishantrop/quasitelegramposter`

Comment: это уже видел и это не то у меня своя форма, мне нужно чтоб заявка приходила через форму ?
я использую AjaxForm месте спинетом и чанком, так что эта точно не то ,
Готовые решия которые использовались 4 года назад столько багов что мама родная

Comment: modTelegram так же устарел из официального источника где можно скачать

Comment: Простите, но ощущение, что Вы ищете кто бы за Вас все сделал. Тут могут подсказать решение, посоветовать что использовать, даже найти ошибку. Но не сделать все за Вас. Все, что Вам нужно легко найти в `google` .